# How to create placemarks manually as in "My Maps"

Tags: google-maps-api-3, marker, manual

I have a fully functioning map using the API v3 with markers placed as a result of database searches, and info windows that pop up correctly. So far, so good.

What I would like to do is to allow the user to place a marker on the map manually, i.e by dragging and dropping a placemark in exactly the same way as google "My Maps" uses to build a map or by clicking on the map.

There are several reasons for doing this, but one is that I would like the user to easily identify a centre point of interest so that I can filter searches within a radius of this point.

I would have thought that this option would be useful to others.

Maybe I am using the wrong search terms for this, and the terms "marker" and "placemark" seem to be interchangeable, which doesnt help, but I cannot formulate a search which has even shown that anyone else is trying to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [this example of the drawing tools](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r282/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html), it allows you to add Markers, Polylines and Polygons, you can customize it to just do Markers.

Here is the documentation for the [Drawing Manager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DrawingManager)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Perfect.